# Question is to remove the duplicates from unsorted array and maintaining the order in time O(N)

Tags: java

I found one code and I don't know how it works.

Please can anybody explain me this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> removeDuplicate(int arr[], int n) {

    int dp[] = new int[100];

    ArrayList<Integer> v = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(dp[arr[i]] == 0) {
            dp[arr[i]] = 1;
            v.add(arr[i]);       
        }
    }
    return v;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through  the array, assign the dp array's value at  index(which is equal to ith element of arr) to 1. While iterating, if you find dp[arr[i]]==1, that means the element is already present in arr, hence ignore it and don't add it in arraylist.
This is O(n) because you are iterating the array once.
The order is also maintained, since you start from the beginning of the array, incrementing by 1 in each iteration and ignoring the element which is already present in the array.
Note this would only work for arr[i]<=100, since you specified dp array of length 100